# Wrap multiple plots together in a single image

Tags: python, plot, facet-wrap

I am trying to wrap numerous plots together, as they are closely related (showing density using 1 continuous and 1 categorical variable, broken down by day of the week, where each day is a different plot). In R, I can either use `grid.arrange()` from `gridExtra` or `facet_wrap` to wrap visualizations together to return to the user as 1 variable and image containing all plots. It looks like this:

[image: All 7 of these plots are combined into 1 image, using <code>grid.arrange()</code>]

How do I do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using matplotlib [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). See this [example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/spectrum_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-spectrum-demo-py).

The layout of the visualization can be initialized with the desired number of rows and columns. Each cell will contain a different subplot.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(7, 7))
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you allude to having used `ggplot2` and `facet_grid()`/`facet_wrap()`, you should check out `plotnine`. From the [homepage](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
(ggplot(mtcars, aes('wt', 'mpg', color='factor(gear)'))
 + geom_point()
 + stat_smooth(method='lm')
 + facet_wrap('~gear'))
```

[image]

I was a long time R user and frankly found the `python` plotting landscape to be sort of a mess. I love being able to use `plotnine` to leverage past `R` experience vs. re-learning the wheel.

Now, the caveat is I came to this answer looking for a true `grid.arrange()`, as facets aren't as flexible. I want 6 mini-plots one one side and a true separate plot on the canvas on the other. This won't do that for me, but figured I'd add an answer here anyway while swinging by :)