# How to arrange different plots in rows and column in python if we are making plots by using plotnine package?

Tags: python, plotnine

In R, we could plot each graph independently and then arrange all or some of the graphs easily by packages like gridExtra.

```
p1 <- ggplot(aes(x1,y1), data=df) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(aes(x2,y2), data=df) + geom_point()

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=1)
```

However, can we do the same thing in Python with **PLOTNINE**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrap multiple plots together in a single image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086651/wrap-multiple-plots-together-in-a-single-image)

Comment: No they have done using matplotlib subplot, I am using plotnine

Comment: Probably, you can't https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/46

Comment: @alec_djinn, that was 3.5 years ago now.  Still no solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found a solution. It is the **patchworklib package**. It allows you to arrange multiple plotnine plot, as you would do with ggplot in R. Give it a look on github: https://github.com/ponnhide/patchworklib